# Use of chi square test of independence on a single level of a factor

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I need to check whether a survey is more likely to be filled out in some regions than in others.

I have a contingency table like so :

```
    Region/survey complete: no yes
    Region1               685 476
    Region2              1159 736
    Region3               761 619
    Region4               762 482
```

Chi squared test of independence < 0.05 which means some regions are more likely to fill out the survey than others.

Chi squared is applied on the 4x2 contingency table, but does it make sense to also test every 2x2 subtable to check whether this particular region is doing better or worse than overall ?

Comment: It makes sense to check 2-by-2 subtables as a follow-up analysis. For details, you may refer to Section 3.3.3 of *Categorical Data Analysis*, 2nd edition, by Alan Agresti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a test for each of the the six 2x2 subtables instead of performing just a single test runs into the [multiple comparisons problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). In short: if the null hypothesis is true and both variables are independent, there will be a random variability between regions. If we use a signification of 5% (for example) and the null hypothesis is true, each test will have a probability of 5% to reject it. Therefore, the more tests, we do, the largest the probability of erroneusly rejecting the null hypothesis.

Then, there are two solutions:

- Using a single test, like testing the whole 4x2 contingency tables.
- Or taking in account that we are performing multiple tests and making corrections to keep the error probability reasonably low.

As Zhanxiong's comment hints, an usual approach is to perform a single test and once the null hypothesis has been rejected (ie. variables have been shown not to be independent) follow up with multiple tests with corrections.

**Edit about multiple tests.**
I suggest reading [biostathandbook](http://www.biostathandbook.com/chiind.html) on post-hoc tests after independence tests. However, as a very short summary, you can use [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) on the pairwise tests, just by dividing significance between the number of possible pairwise tests. That is, since there are 6 subtables, you can reject independence in any of them if the test in the subtable yields a p-value lower than alpha/6 (ie. 0.05/6). This way, the probability of a type I error in one or more pairwise tests will remain below alpha.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do I perform these corrections ?